# The problem of FormDataContentDisposition in Jersey File Upload

Tags: upload, jersey, multipart

```
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataContentDisposition;  
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataParam;  
@Path("/files")  
public class FileUploadService {  
    @POST  
    @Path("/upload")  
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)  
    @Produces({"text/plain","application/xml","application/json"})

    public Response uploadPdfFile(  @FormDataParam("file") InputStream fileInputStream,
            @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileMetaData) throws Exception
    {
            //String UPLOAD_PATH = "f://";
        String UPLOAD_PATH = "c://temp//";
    try
    {
        int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[102400];
        
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(UPLOAD_PATH +
   fileMetaData.getFileName()));
        //OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(UPLOAD_PATH + "xx.txt"));
        
        while ((read = fileInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) 
        {
        out.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) 
        {
        throw new WebApplicationException("Error while uploading file. Please try again !!");
        }
    return Response.ok("Data uploaded successfully !!").build();
    }
}
```

A code of Jersey upload was running. If I use OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(UPLOAD_PATH + "xx.txt")), it is good and I can see the xx.txt file in c:\temp folder.

However, if I use OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(UPLOAD_PATH + fileMetaData.getFileName())), it said Data uploaded successfuly!!, but I cannot see anything in c:\temp folder.

Did this FormDataContentDisposition have any bug? Or I use it in wrong way?

The line "return Response.ok("Data uploaded successfully !!").build();" will return "Data uploaded successfully !!".

However, if I change the line "return Response.ok("Data uploaded successfully !!").build();   to     return Response.ok("Data uploaded successfully !!"+fileMetaData.getFileName()).build();
I got the results of "Data uploaded successfully !!C:CodingWeb services16.JAX-RS File Upload Exampletest.txt".

Why did fileMetaData.getFileName() return "C:CodingWeb services16.JAX-RS File Upload Exampletest.txt"?

Comment: Did you check the client side?

Comment: I just made a try. The code didn't work in Eclipse browser, but worked  in Chrome. However, the line "return Response.ok("Data uploaded successfully !!").build();" returned ugly xml message.